# svn "no element found" error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to subversioning. I wanted to checkout already existing project in my system. But, when I did this in console:

```
svn checkout urlname
```

It asked me for password, but I gave it wrong password by mistake. When I tried it second timee, it didn't ask me for password but gave an error message:

```
unable to connect to a repository at URL
The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at    
line1: no element found (urlname)
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start Menu > Tortoise SVN > Settings to show the settings dialog box. From Saved Data dialog, click on 'clear' button beside Authentication Data to make Tortoise Subversion forget the saved password.

However, no element found error message suggests that you have wrong URL. You might want to recheck it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with authentication.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that the URL is not correct. When you browse to the SVN rep via the http/https take a note of the full url to the repository that you want to browse to.

```
e.g. httpx://192.168.0.xxx/svn
```

Will give me the same error (unable to connect to a repository at URL
The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at
line1: no element found (urlname)

However when I browse to `httpx://192.168.0.xxx/svn/NAMEOFREPO`

Where the repo structure would look like

```
e.g. httpx://192.168.0.xxx/svn/NAMEOFREPO/trunk
```

you can now download the code :)

Comment: Also, if the repo is using VisualSVN, right next to where it says Revision: HEAD, there is a checkout button that will give you the url to use to checkout.  No url hacking required.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using TortoiseSVN or the SVN command line client?

If you're using the command line client, take a look at the `.subversion\auth` directory in your home directory. This is where all authentication information is stored. Most likely, the login information is stored in `.subversion\auth\svn.simple`.

Root around there to find the authentication information. Delete the file that has your authentication information stored in it. In fact, you can delete all the files in this directory. Subversion will simply recreate them once you try to log in again.

In TortoiseSVN, there's a place to clear our your Authentication information under settings.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the correct password using:

svn --password (your password here) checkout urlname

Comment: I tried it, it asked me the password again! But it is still not working, I entered the username and password for entering the repo! However, it is still giving me the same error!

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete output, including the error message? "No element found" seems like an XML error, not specifically an svn error. Can you open the URL you are requesting in a browser?

Comment: Yes, I can open the url in the browser!

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use VisualSVN Server and get the error `svn: E130003: Malformed XML: no element found` when addressing the repository, most likely the problem is with the URL you enter.

Subversion client displays this error in case the URL used leads to the web interface. The URL has to lead to the Subversion repository. To get rid of the error, just click the **Checkout** button in the web interface and copy-paste the correct URL to the Subversion client.

Read the article [KB102: Subversion client errors caused by inappropriate repository URL](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00102/) for the detailed steps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have fixed this issue using the option `Steal lock` ( `checkbox` in bottom left area of the form when you are setting a lock to repository files )
this error is caused because some files it seems to be unlocked but really it isn't ( verify this from the Explorer window clicking the properties of the file, and then, SVN Properties.... then you can see the real state of the file )

Answer (score 0):

I see that most answers are guessing what the problem might be, but to make a precise diagnostic you better trace/inspect the SVN network traffic as indicated in https://subversion.apache.org/docs/community-guide/debugging.html#net-trace:

- With Wireshark
- With socat
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. navigate the URL in the browser (eg chrome)
2. click on the checkout button [image]

[image]

3. copy the link from the checkout button
4. paste it in the url of svn