# TortoiseSvn can't use domain name but can use with ip address

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

when I us tortoissvn with domain it display：

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL   ‘＊＊＊＊＊＊＊’
>   The XML response contains invalid XML  Malformed XML:no element found

but use ip address it' ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [svn "no element found" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195532/svn-no-element-found-error)

Answer (score 0):

The error you get indicates that you entered an incorrect URL. Unlike web browsers, Subversion clients (except TortoiseSVN) are unable to access the repositories collection (i.e. list) that's usually can be viewed in a web browser.

In other words, you are unable to access e.g. https://svn.example.com/svn/ URL using Subversion clients (except TortoiseSVN beginning with version 1.7). You should specify the URL to *repository* (or it's subtree) explicitly.